# Java Annotation to enforce a compile-time minimum value of a constant?

Tags: java, annotations, constants, final

I'm using the term "constant" loosely.  I'm referring specifically to `public static int`'s, which the compiler is free to treat as immediates.

I have legacy code that ensures that a value is established as 3 or greater in the following inelegant way:

```
public SomeClass
{
    public static final int BORDER;
    static
    {
        BORDER = 3;
        if (BORDER < 3) throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            String.format("This program was compiled with a BORDER of [%d], "+
                          "and a value of 3 or greater MUST be used.", BORDER));
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a standard annotation that can enforce this at compile-time.

I imagine something akin to

```
@Min(3)
public static final int BORDER=2;  //compile-time error
```

or

```
@Enforce("BORDER >= 3")
public static final int BORDER=2;  // compile-time error
```

Does some facility approximating this exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Constant Value Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#constant-value-checker) of the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/) has an [`@IntRange`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/common/value/qual/IntRange.html) annotation that does what you want.

If you annotate the type of a variable like this:

```java
@IntRange(from=0, to=11) int month;
```

then at compile time, the compiler will issue an error anywhere in the program that `month` might take on a value outside of the range 0..11.  You can write just one of the bounds; in your case, you would use

```java
public static final @IntRange(from=3) int BORDER=2;  // compile-time error
```

Comment: Does this allow the compiler to replace occurrences of BORDER with the immediate value everywhere used (when in valid range)?  Or does it remove it's `final`-ness?  The documentation looks a little like the datatype itself is replaced everywhere, but I'm new to annotations.

Comment: A type annotation does not affect compiler optimizations.  Note that `final` refers to the variable and is not part of the type.  A change to the datatype is different than a change to the variable; that is, type annotations and `public static final` are orthogonal.

Comment: No, I understand the charter of `final`; I'm talking about their documentation.  Look carefully at their use of "now has type" [22.1.1](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#constant-value-checker-type-annotations).  You'll see them use language such as `int i = 1;     // i has type:  @IntVal({1}) int` and `i = 2;     // i now has type:  @IntVal({2}) int`, etc.  Java states that it not only _can_ replace `static final int` with actual (immediate) values where the ID appears, but that it _will_.  The question then to me becomes whether or not the compiler is still regarding this as such.